# (Java newbie) Instantiating unknown number of objects

Tags: java, oop

Java/OO newbie question:

`main` instantiates `Track` class. Now I want that object--`track1`--to instantiate many `Clip` objects, the number of which will not be known until runtime.  From inside the `Track` class I can make a new `Clip` like this:

```
Clip clip1 = new Clip(); // this is track1.clip1 from main
```

But when I want to add more clips based on user input, how and where do I do this? From `main`, something like:

```
Clip track1.clipX = new Clip();
```

How do I name and reference `Clip` objects when I don't know how many there will be?

Comment: just as an aside, java classes, by convention, start with a captial letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use a Collection (like a List or Set) to hold the multiple Clip objects:

```
int numberOfClips = 10;
List<Clip> clips = new ArrayList<Clip>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClips; i++) {
    Clip clip = new Clip();
    clips.add(clip);
}
```

This would add 10 Clip objects to the array `clips`.  Instead of hardcoding to 10, you could set numberOfClips based on the user's input.

[The List Java docs page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.htm) describes all of the methods you can call on Lists, so that will show you how to get items in the List, remove items from the List, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a `List` to hold the clips in `Track`?

```
public class Track {
    ...
    List<Clip> clips;

    void addClip(Clip clip) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And something like that for the `Clip`:

```
public class Clip {
    private int index;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

And from the `main`:

```
Track track = new Track();
Clip aClip = new Clip(1, "clip name");
track.addClip(aClip);
Clip anotherClip = new Clip(2, "another name");
track.addClip(anotherClip);
...
```